# Debugtoolkit does not work in firefox, but works in internet explorer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestion on troubleshooting why the Cakephp_debugkit stops working in firefox. Today it worked for a few hours and suddenly it just stoped working. When i check IE explorer it works without any issues.

Working in cake 3.8

In app.php:

```
 'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

In bootstrap.php

```
Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

Comment: clear browser cache

Comment: That was easy. Thank you. I dont know why i didnt think of that. I was troubleshooting the code before trying to clear the cache. ;)